# Storcli64 not rebuilding replaced disk

Tags: lsi, megaraid, storcli

One of the drives in our LSI-based RAID failed (Avago 3108 MegaRaid). We pulled the drive and replaced it with a similar disk (cap/speed). Autorebuild is enabled, however the status of the disk (128:7) shows it's state is JBOD instead of Onln, so it looks like the autorebuild didn't work:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EID:Slt DID State DG     Size Intf Med SED PI SeSz Model            Sp Type 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
128:0   140 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:1   137 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:2   151 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:3   144 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:4   171 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:5   138 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:6   147 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:7   172 JBOD   - 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  512B ST10000NM0096    U  -    
128:8   132 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:9   148 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:10  158 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:11  136 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:12  141 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:13  160 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:14  154 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:15  155 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:16  150 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:17  134 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:18  157 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:19  139 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:20  133 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:21  146 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:22  149 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
128:23  159 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:0   166 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:1   170 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:2   167 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:3   169 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:4   168 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:5   156 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:6   135 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:7   142 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:8   161 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:9   145 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:10  143 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
129:11  131 Onln   0 9.094 TB SAS  HDD N   N  4 KB ST10000NM0206    U  -    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The last time we replaced a drive, it did get rebuilt and added to the array. I double-checked the status of autorebuild and confirmed it's on..

```
------------------
Ctrl_Prop   Value 
------------------
AutoRebuild ON    
------------------
```

The event log from storcli64 shows the remove/replace event, but doesn't show any issue with an incompatible configuration, for example:

```
Event Description: PD 98(e0x80/s7)
Event Description: PD 98(e0x80/s7) Path 5000c500868172c9  reset (Type 03)
Event Description: Removed: PD 98(e0x80/s7) Info: enclPd=80, scsiType=0, portMap=00, sasAddr=5000c500868172c9,0000000000000000
Event Description: State change on PD 98(e0x80/s7) from FAILED(11) to UNCONFIGURED_BAD(1)
Event Description: Inserted: PD ac(e0x80/s7)
Event Description: Inserted: PD ac(e0x80/s7) Info: enclPd=80, scsiType=0, portMap=00, sasAddr=5000c500a6f54715,0000000000000000
Event Description: PD ac(e0x80/s7) Inquiry info: Info- SEAG ST10000NM0096    00C9088122 9 TB
```

I'm wondering if the specs of the disk itself might be preventing it from being added to the DG.  The SeSz value is different for the replacement drive (512B vs 4K), but the speed, capacity and connectivity (SAS) are the same.

Comment: It is something specific to SuperMicro. I read they say you can't mix 512 and 4k sector size. https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=26636

Comment: Check also here: https://support.pelco.com/s/article/RAID-controller-of-VxStorage-hardware-doesn-t-support-different-sector-size-HDDs-4k-vs-512?language=en_US

Comment: That would definitely explain it. Thanks for the reference!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [FAQ](https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=26636) you can't mix 512 and 4k disks in one DG. For me this is the reason you get this disk as JBOD.

Also you can check [here](https://support.pelco.com/s/article/RAID-controller-of-VxStorage-hardware-doesn-t-support-different-sector-size-HDDs-4k-vs-512?language=en_US) for explanation about the above from other reference.